I have a simple web server on an ESP8266. At first, it runs fine, but after a while with no requests it goes down. Pinging the IP address times out
I am a beginner, but I coded a simple web server on an ESP8266.
Part of my code follows:
    # Accept an incoming connection request
    print("\nWaiting for a request\n")
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print('Got a request from %s' % str(addr))
    request = conn.recv(1024)
    request = str(request)
    print('\nContent = %s' % request)
    response = web_page()
    conn.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n')
    conn.send('Content-Type: text/html\n')
    conn.send('Connection: close\n\n')
    conn.sendall(response)
    conn.close()

When a request is received, it responds with a web page that contains temperature and humidity data from a DHT22 sensor. When I start it, it runs fine for a while.  If no new requests come in, the server seems to go down.  When I ping the IP address, it starts by returning timeouts and after five or six pings it wakes up again.  Any ideas?
Pinging the IP address of the server seems to wake it up again.
